# How to access Session variables in Popup portlet - Liferay 6.2

Tags: java, session-variables, liferay-6

In an application I have a portlet rendered in a popup menu.

Click of a button renders the popup modal box and PortletA is rendered in it.

I want to access a pre set session variable in the doView of PortletA.

But the value is always null.

Can a portlet in popup menu has access to session variables in Liferay 6.2?

Comment: Can you post code snippet in question? Ideally you should able to access session variable.

Comment: While posting the code make sure your snippet contains the code of setting and getting of the attribute fro session.